# Purpose of the <head> and <body> tags

Tags: html

I want to know what is the purpose of head and body tag.

Like when i use `<title>` tag in `<body>` section ,i got the same thing and when i  use `<p>` tag in `<head>` section ,that i got the same thing which i used to get in `<body>` section,So what is concept to define a body or head section.

Or It is only understanding that this kind of tag will use in body section and these tag will be used in head section.

It will be better if you can provide me concept document too for this.

Comment: start here: http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As per the MDN on `<head>`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head)

> The HTML `<head>` element represents a collection of metadata about the
>   document, including links to or definitions of scripts and style
>   sheets.

What this is basically saying is that everything that goes in the `<head>` tag is not seen by the user (basically), but is used to include relevant information and dynamic content that is processed by the browser.

[About the `<body>` tag:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body)

> The HTML `<body>` element represents the content of an HTML document.
>   There is only one `<body>` element in a document.

This means that everything that the user sees on the page goes in the `<body>` tag (basically), and that there is only one.

Do some research yourself, and see what else you can find!

Answer (score 1):

The head tag is basically used to bring in necessary CSS and JS as well as define some meta information about the page. Items in the body tag are generally what is actually rendered.

There is a lot more to it, but that is the difference in its most basic form. You don't want to be using the title tag in the body. Any sort of semantic piece that is used to render the page should be in the body.